# What is the time complexity of function2?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
int function2(int n)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int sum = 0;
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k += 1)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i *= 3)
        {
            j = i;
            while (j > 1)
            {
                sum += 1;
                j /= 3; 
            }
        } 
    }
    return sum; 
}
```

I understand that:

The outermost for loop runs n times.
The inner for loop runs log3(n) times.
The innermost while loop runs log3(i) times, and since i increases at a rate of log3(n), the while loop runs log3(log3(n)) times?
So the total complexity is O(n * logn * log(logn))?

But thinking about it, wouldn't the while loop run the same number of times that i has been multiplied by 3?
so couldn't we rewrite it as:

```
for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    for (i = 1; i <= log3(n); i++)
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

? in which case it'd be O(n * logn * logn)?

Someone also said it was O(n * logn) because it's a harmonic series? how is this a harmonic series?

Comment: "_and since i increases at a rate of log3(n), the while loop runs log3(log3(n)) times_": That's not how it works. You need to form the sum of `log3(i)` over all `i` that are iterated by the loop. These are all `i = 3^m` from `m=0` to `m=log3(n)`. `log3(3^m) = m`, so you are summing `m` from `0` to `log3(n)` which gives you a leading order `(log(n))^2`. This already accounts for both inner loops and you only need to multiply with the outer. (These are rough estimates, not a proper analysis for which you should find exact upper and lower bounds.)

Comment: @user17732522 I understood that the innermost while loop runs the number of times i gets multiplied by 3, or m=log3(n) times, each time, so the total complexity is O(nlognlogn)?

Comment: @ZhouFang Yes, your second line of reasoning in the question is correct. And for the last one "_how is this a harmonic series?_": It simply isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the total complexity is O(n * logn * log(logn))?

No.

> wouldn't the while loop run the same number of times that i has been multiplied by 3

Yes.

> in which case it'd be O(n * logn * logn)?

Yes.

The inner most loop will loop log<sub><sub>3</sub></sub> times for a given iteration of the middle loop, but  is a power of 3, so actually with each next iteration of the middle loop, the inner loop will do **one** more iteration than before.

The number of inner loop iterations for the combined iterations of the middle loop -- for one outer iteration -- is the following sum:

1 + 2 + 3 + ... + log<sub><sub>3</sub></sub>

This is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), and so this is O(log²).

Bringing the outer loop into the equation gives: O(log²)